# Can I use silverlight with other serverside languages?

Tags: .net, silverlight

Is it possible to integrate silverlight with PHP. I'm currently using flash, so was wondering if silverlight can be used as a replacement.

Thanks,
Roger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you should be able to use "any" server side language, as long as you use a supported transport layer using xml or Json (or something similar), like this [tutorial shows](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/silverlight-2-php-tutorial-transmitting-data-using-json)

Answer (score 2):

Silverlight, like Flash, is a *client-side* technology.  It can be served from any Web server (with suitable MIME type configuration), and does not depend on the technology used to serve the containing page.  It can therefore be incorporated into PHP, JSP or static HTML pages, just as Flash can be.

That said, if your Silverlight application needs to post data back to the server (e.g. a game posting high scores or a business application posting user inputs or making queries against a database), the built-in comms support is mainly aimed at SOAP Web services or ADO.NET Data Services.  So if your application needs to talk to the server after the user has downloaded it, you'll want to check out how well Silverlight's SOAP implementation works with your PHP Web services.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use Silverlight with PHP or any other Server-side language for that matter. (Worth noting as the question title could be confusing some, that Silverlight is purely a client side technology and not server-side.)

You say you currently use Flash, if flash is accessing any data provided by your PHP server-side code, there's a good chance Silverlight will be able to access that same data with no or very little code changes in your PHP code.

Check this thread on the Silverlight forum http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/142967/319181.aspx which discusses using Silverlight with PHP. Also doing a few Google searches on "Silverlight in PHP" will give you a whole bunch of resources to look at.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

yes. you can use silverlight with other serverside languages